# Eclipse, Maven, Subclipse & Multiple Modules

Tags: eclipse, maven, subclipse

I have a project in SVN that I have checked out into a new install of eclipse (Indigo).  Previously, with the m2e and subclipse plugins I was able to check out as a Maven project - but this no longer seems possible.  I read somewhere, however, that checking out and then converting to a maven project is the way to go.

I've done that, but my project has a number of nested modules - each of which I would like to appear as separate projects in the eclipse workspace.  This used to be possible and specified during checkout, but no longer seems to work.

Is this possible and, if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the m2e subclipse connector - which I had previously failed to find.  This set it all out exactly as I had hoped it would.

Comment: To all those who wanted to know (like me) where the connector can be found you can use this link (http://www.shareyourwork.org/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/eclipse_indigo_maven_and_svn) In short, in case the link dies, I found it in the m2eMarketplace

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't use the right version of M2Eclipse :

Indigo is Eclipse 3.7, and "m2eclipse is compatible with Eclipse 3.5.2 and 3.6.1" (source : http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html).

"m2e is tested against Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) and 3.7 (Indigo)" (http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)

Comment: I am definitely using m2e - in most respects it seems to work, just not in terms of project setup...

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/q4e/

We use that over m2e and provides better menu support for manage dependencies and importing Maven2 projects.

Comment: I installed this plugin, but it still doesn't seem to allow me to have all of my modules appear as if they are separate projects in the workspace, which is how I used to have everything set up - and would like to again.

Comment: How did you import the project into eclipse? The steps that I use are: 1. import Maven2 project, 2. point it to the root dir of all the projects, 3. leave bring parent in unchecked, 4. import. And it lists all the projects found in the root as separate projects in eclipse. Each sub-module has its own POM correct?

Comment: Each module has it's own POM.  I'm importing it using Subclipse

Comment: Then I would recommend using the import "existing Maven2 project" option. I also use subclipse, but don't use the svn import through eclipse.